# Sweet alert stopping unless i press a confirm button

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I have a big validation javascript rule - list before i should allow the submission of a form..
To keep the example simple I show only first 4 rules syntax simplified...

```
$("#SubmitForm").submit(function() {
     
// Some variables defined...

        
        if (Condition check 1)
{                                   
                Swal.fire({ 
                title: 'Attention!',
                text: "Warning Text1",
                icon: 'warning',
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                confirmButtonText: 'Return'
                })
                return false; 
        }else if (Validation Rule 2){ 
           Swal.fire({       
              title: 'Attention',
              icon: 'error',
              html: 'Notify user for possible problem',
              showCloseButton: false,
              focusConfirm: false,
              confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
              confirmButtonText: 'Return'
            })
           return false;
        }else if (Validation Rule 3){ 
              Swal.fire({         
              title: 'Attention',
              icon: 'warning',
              html: 'Warning Msg with options menu',
              showCloseButton: false,
              reverseButtons: true,
              focusConfirm: true,
              confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
              cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonText: 'Continue',
              
            }).then((result) => {
              if (result.isConfirmed) {
                **return true; //Should Continue to next validation check**
              }else{
                return false;  
              }
              
            });
            // Wait for user's choice...
        }else if (Validation Rule 4){ 
            return Swal.fire({
```

........

How can I continue to the next validation rule 4, in the case of Validation Rule 3, user presses Continue.

(I'm showing you simplified code to keep it clean as possible...)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is moving the whole `else if (Validation Rule 4){ ... }` block (without the *else if* of course) inside the `if (result.isConfirmed) {}` condition.

An other option would be setting some hidden input value that will trigger *Validation Rule 4* and then call submit the form again calling `$("#SubmitForm").submit()`.

Comment: First way of yours would mess up the code since this is a 40 Validation Rule page so in the end I would miss the idea which Rule am I checking to... Could u explain me little more your second thought ?

Comment: I see. The second thought is adding `<input type="hidden" name="validation_3_ok" value="false" />` to the form HTML and then inside the `if (result.isConfirmed) {}` condition something like:
`$("input[name=validation_3_ok]").val(true)`
`event.stopPropagation();` (edit the first row: `$("#SubmitForm").submit(function(event) {`)
`$("#SubmitForm").submit();`

And add a condition for *validation_3_ok* to *Validation Rule 3*.